# regex for textual dates? (aka source code for php's strtotime )

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm working on the search box for an events website. I've been recording the searches people make and alot of people are entering a {date}+{keyword} combo.

example searches:

```
jazz 5th november
dj shadow tonight
2nd october live music
```

so I need to write/find a regex that can match textual dates from within a longer string.

I'm thinking the easiest way to do this would be to work from the source code for PHP's `strtotime()` , assuming it runs on regular expressions.

Can anyone give me any tips for obtaining the source or alternatively has anyone come across any good regular expressions for textual dates?

Comment: Given the wide variety of date formats (and you even add "tonight" in), I don't think a regex is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809985/how-to-find-dates-in-the-sentence-using-nlp-regex-in-python/3810334#3810334), how about using this to find dates (or things that at least look like dates) within the text and then try parsing those:

```
\b                     # match a word boundary
(?:                    # either...
 (?:                   # match the following one to three times:
  (?:                  # either
   \d+                 # a number,
   (?:\.|st|nd|rd|th)* # followed by a dot, st, nd, rd, or th (optional)
   |                   # or a month name
   (?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*)
  )
  [\s./-]*             # followed by a date separator or whitespace (optional)
 ){1,3}                # do this one to three times
|                      # or match a "colloquial" date and capture in backref 1:
(to(?:day|ni(?:te|ght)|morrow)|next\s+(?:week|month|year))
)
\b                     # and end at a word boundary.
```

So if you have a match, and backref `$1` is empty, then a literal date was presumably found; if `$1` is not empty, it found a date like "today" or "next week". Of course, this is only going to work with dates in English text, and it's probably not going to be very reliable.

```
if (preg_match(
    '%\b                   # match a word boundary
    (?:                    # either...
     (?:                   # match the following one to three times:
      (?:                  # either
       \d+                 # a number,
       (?:\.|st|nd|rd|th)* # followed by a dot, st, nd, rd, or th (optional)
       |                   # or a month name
       (?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*)
      )
      [\s./-]*             # followed by a date separator or whitespace (optional)
     ){1,3}                # do this one to three times
    |                      # or ...
    (?:to(?:day|ni(?:te|ght)|morrow)|next\s+(?:week|month|year))
    )
    \b                    # and end at a word boundary.%ix', 
    $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
        $colloq = $regs[1];   // don't know what happens if $1 didn't participate in the match, though.
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) recognizes every format that is explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats). You could take the formats right from there and build the regular expression on your own.

Here’s an example for the [time formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.time):

```
// Uses Symbols
$frac = "(?:\.[0-9]+)"; //".21342", ".85"
$hh = "(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])"; // "04", "7", "12"
$HH = "(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4])"; // "04", "7", "19"
$meridian = "(?:[AaPp]\.?[Mm]\.?[\0\t ])"; // "A.m.", "pM", "am."
$MM = "(?:[0-5][0-9])"; // "00", "12", "59"
$II = "(?:[0-5][0-9])"; // "00", "12", "59"
$space = "(?:[ \t])";
$tz = "(?:\(?[A-Za-z]{1,6})?|[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[_/][A-Z][a-z]+)+)"; // "CEST", "Europe/Amsterdam", "America/Indiana/Knox"
$tzcorrection = "(?:(?:GMT)?[+-]$hh:?$MM?)"; // "+0400", "GMT-07:00", "-07:00"

// 12 Hour Notation
$Hour_only_with_meridian = "(?:$hh$space?$meridian)"; // "4 am", "5PM"
$Hour_and_minutes_with_meridian = "(?:$hh[.:]$MM$space?$meridian)"; // "4:08 am", "7:19P.M."
$Hour_minutes_and_seconds_with_meridian = "(?:$hh[.:]$MM[.:]$II$space?$meridian)"; // "4:08:37 am", "7:19:19P.M."
$Hour_minutes_seconds_and_fraction_with_meridian = "(?:$hh:$MM:$II[.:][0-9]+$meridian)"; // "4:08:39:12313am"

// 24 Hour Notation
$Hour_and_minutes = "($t?$HH[.:]$MM)"; // "04:08", "19.19", "T23:43"
$Hour_and_minutes_no_colon = "(?:t?$HH$MM)"; // "0408", "t1919", "T2343"
$Hour_minutes_and_seconds = "(?:t?$HH$[.:]$MM[.:]$II)"; // "04.08.37", "t19:19:19"
$Hour_minutes_and_seconds_no_colon = "(?:t?$HH$MM$II)"; // "040837", "T191919"
$Hour_minutes_seconds_and_timezone = "(?:t?$HH[.:]$MM[.:]$II$space?(?:$tzcorrection|$tz))"; // "040837CEST", "T191919-0700"
$Hour_minutes_seconds_and_fraction = "(?:t?$HH[.:]$MM[.:]$II$frac)"; // "04.08.37.81412", "19:19:19.532453"
$Time_zone_information = "(?:$tz|$tzcorrection)"; // "CEST", "Europe/Amsterdam", "+0430", "GMT-06:00"
```