# Identify date-related text in a longer message

Tags: php, datetime

I'm currently writing a script that would extract all the dates from a message and convert them to timestamps. PHP's strtotime (similar to Unix's `date -c 'some date'`) would be perfect for this, as it recognizes all kinds of dates, such as:

- 5pm today
- 2010-11-15 16:30
- Thursday 8:00

However, I'm having trouble finding those dates in the first place. For example, in the following string,

> I'll be there for dinner tomorrow at 9:00pm

I need to isolate "tomorrow at 9:00pm", as that's the part that strtotime recognizes.

Is there a regular expression or something similar that would return me all dates that can be parsed by strtotime?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845145/regex-for-textual-dates-aka-source-code-for-phps-strtotime

Comment: hopefully you are not dueling with France language,something like `novembre ` may make your regexp work header

Comment: The most helpful answer was the link by rojoca; I managed to hack together a similar regex

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is [date_parse](http://php.net/date_parse). A regular expression that matches *any* format accepted by `strtotime` would be huge.

An example of date_parse:

```
$str = "I'll be there for dinner tomorrow at 9:00pm";
$parsed = date_parse($str);
print_r($parsed);
```

It would output something like this (I removed the unimportant parts from it to make it the result lighter):

```
Array
(
    [year] => 
    [month] => 
    [day] => 
    [hour] => 21               // 9:00pm
    [minute] => 0              // 9:00pm  
    [second] => 0              // 9:00pm
    [fraction] => 0
    [warning_count] => 1
    [is_localtime] => 1
    [zone_type] => 2
    [zone] => -540
    [is_dst] => 
    [tz_abbr] => I
    [relative] => Array
        (
            [year] => 0
            [month] => 0
            [day] => 1          // tomorrow (would be -1 for yesterday, etc.)
            [hour] => 0
            [minute] => 0
            [second] => 0
        )

)
```

Whether this works for you depends primarily on what your input looks like. If you have more than one instance of a date in your input string, it will not work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I do need to handle more than one instance of a date.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be totally efficient, but should work for any date string that consists of up to 5 words in length.  I would write the function, but I think you'll get the idea with the comments below...

```
$words = explode(' ',$original_string);

// Use the array_chunk() function break up this array into 1-word,
// 2-word, 3-word, and 4-word long substrings of the original string

// Reform them back into strings and pass each one through strtodate()
```

Comment: If your original string is N-words long, you'll end up calling strtodate() a little less than 5*N times.  If you look for up to 6-word long substrings, it's 6*N times, etc.