# What would be the best approach to finding a date in a freeform text? 

Tags: php, regex, perl, date

What would be the best approach to finding a date in a freeform text? A post where a user may place a date in it in several different ways such as:

1. July 14th & 15th
2. 7/14 & 7/15
3. 7-14 & 7-15
4. Saturday 14th and Sunday 15th
5. Saturday July 14th and 15th

and so on. Is regex my best choice for this type of thing with `preg_match`? I would also like to search if there are two dates, one for a start date and a second for an end date, but in the text I'm searching there may be one date or two.

This is my PHP code so far:

```
$dates1 = '01-01';
$dates2 = 'July 14th & 15th';
$dates3 = '7/14 & 7/15';
$dates4 = '7-14 & 7-15';
$dates5 = 'Saturday 14th and Sunday 15th';
$dates6 = 'Saturday July 14th and 15th';

$regexes = array(
        '/\s(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)\/\d{1,2}/',  //finds a date
        '/\s(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)-\d{1,2}/',  //finds another date
        '%\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])\b%', //finds date format dd-mm or dd.mm
        );
foreach($regexes as $regex){
preg_match($regex,$dates,$matches);
}
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: sounds very painful, are you sure you cant constrain the data

Comment: Yeah it is painful! Especially trying to learn regex to do this. The only thing that would make things easier is most posts are for the coming friday and saturday. The post dates are in a format i can use with php and use a strtotime with the sat and sunday keywords. But i would like to be able to find the 7/14 or the July 14th and 15th.

Comment: Sounds painful indeed. Are the 6 dates provided the only formats you expect?

Comment: no it could be unlimited. I figure it will take time to add all the ones i can think of. Just want to make sure I head in the right direction before beginning.

Comment: I don't see why you cant constrain the user, you will always need a human to check the non matches if you don't.

Comment: Sorry I cant constrain because its from another site that im trying to gather the dates. Otherwise yes I would constrain the user entry.

Comment: lets how you haver permission to scrape the other site.

Comment: Agreed, this is a very broad set of patterns to match. You can combine and simplify your first 2 regex patterns to `/\s(1[0-2]|[1-9])[\-\/]([0-2]?[1-9]|3[0-1])[\-\/](\d{4}|\d{2})/` which would match any number `1-12` followed by a dash/slash followed by a number `1-31` followed by another delimiter (dash/slash) and finally followed by a 2 or 4 digit year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a class called DateTime that manages timestamps. It lets you convert between strings and DateTime objects pretty easily... Providing that your strings use the formats PHP gives you.

For example,

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m', '01-01');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d', 'July 14');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
```

That said, here's what I'd do:

Create an array of acceptable formats, in order of priority:

```
$formats = array("d-m", "j-M-Y" ... );
```

Work with RegEx to massage your inputs so that they match your formats.

```
// Add the current year to this one:
$dates1 = '01-01';

// Split these into "July 14" and "July 15", and add the year
//  (this one will be the toughest)
$dates2 = 'July 14th & 15th';

// Split these into "7/14" and "7/15", and add the year
$dates3 = '7/14 & 7/15';

// Split these into "7-14" and "7-15", and add the year
$dates4 = '7-14 & 7-15';

// Split these, and add a month and year
$dates5 = 'Saturday 14th and Sunday 15th';

// Split these, and add a year:
$dates6 = 'Saturday July 14th and 15th';
```

Try to construct a DateTime object:

```
$date = false;
foreach ($formats as $format)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateString);
    if ($date) break;
}
```

Comment: Of course, this is all assuming that your timestamp exists in a single variable, and not as a substring of some larger text...

Comment: If it is within some larger text, however, then the benefit to using this method is that you don't have to write up massive confusing RegExes; rather, you can let DateTime do the heavy lifting. For example, if the text was "I turn 21 on June 21", you can perform a pattern match of "/[a-zA-Z]* [0-9]*/" to extract "turn 21" and "June 21". Of course, "turn 21" is not a valid date, and so DateTime::createFromFormat will return false... But when it attempts to match "June 21", you'll get a valid object, and that last foreach loop will break.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the text you're attempting to parse contains *only* the date text you're interested in. If so, I would modify the UI so that if two dates are required, then two text fields must be entered. This removes the problem of figuring out how to separate them.

And now with one date in text, I'd hand the whole text to `strtotime()`. That solves the second problem. If you get nonsense back (and `strtotime()` will tell you if it's nonsense), you can tell the user you couldn't understand the date given.

Comment: I don't think that's a very safe assumption to make. He could be trying to pull all date references out of a forum post for example.

Comment: That is why I said that that was what I was presuming.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Perl answer to a very similar question with a not-very-sophisticated brute-force solution here:
[Extract inconsistently formatted date from string (date parsing, NLP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445358/extract-inconsistently-formatted-date-from-string-date-parsing-nlp/3445837#3445837)

The basic approach is to break the freeform text into chunks of consecutive characters that might be dates, then see if those characters parse as a valid looking date. In Perl I can (ab)use the Date::Parse module to do that. If PHP doesn't have an equivalent module that parses arbitrary freeform dates, you could approximate it with a few regexen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the date formats PHP considers valid: http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Ideally you'd want to have the dates isolated and then use `strtotime()`, but since that is not an option you are stuck in a hard place. You'll have to quantify all of the formats you want to support and create a set of regular expressions that cover all of the bases. The list mentioned above is a good place to start.

Realize, however, that you're going to have trouble guessing what a date like `1/2/2005` means... is that January 2nd or, as is standard in many areas, would that be February 1st? In ambiguous cases you might have to toss them out or send them somewhere to be manually evaluated.